# Writing an If condition at React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, if-statement, jsx

I try to write an if statement inside the loop but it gives an error. I tried to use {} but it does not work too, how can I write it properly.

```
`<Option
      optionText={option}      

 colorText = {props.colors[index]}
      priceText = {props.prices[index]}
      rangeText = {props.ranges[index]}
      domainText = {props.domains[index]}

    if(this.props.colorText == this.props.domainText){
      //I want to write a if condition here but it says Identifier expected
    }
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
    />
    </div> 
      )) 
    }  
  </div>`
```

import React from 'react';

const Option = (props) => (

```
<p className="add-option-color">
  props.rangeText = {(props.colorText == props.domainText) ? props.rangeText : 
    props.domainText}
  {props.count}. Product: {props.optionText} , Color: {props.rangeText} , Price: {props.priceText}</p>


    <button  className="button button--link" onClick={(e) => {
        props.handleDeleteOption(props.optionText,props.colorText,props.priceText);
      }}
    >
      remove
    </button>
    <hr></hr>
  </div>
);

export default Option;
```

Comment: what is the prop you want to apply if the condition is true?

Comment: That if-statement is not inside a loop. It is inside a JSX element, and you can't write code inside a JSX element, unless it is as the properties value.

Comment: use ternary operator

Answer (score 2):

The clean way is yo use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like in this example :

```
<Option
      optionText={option}
      colorText = {props.colors[index]}
      priceText = {props.prices[index]}
      rangeText = {props.ranges[index]}
      domainText = {props.domains[index]}
      YOURPROPS = {(this.props.colorText == this.props.domainText) ? VALUEIFTRUE : 
      VALUEIFFALSE}
      count= {index + 1}
      handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
/>
```

Comment: Why back tick??

Comment: It was a missclick, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a function like as following --->

```
getAllParams() {
        if(this.props.colorText == this.props.domainText){
          return "pass what you want pass"
        } else {
          return
        }
    }
    render() {    
    <Option
              optionText={option}      
              colorText = {props.colors[index]}
              priceText = {props.prices[index]}
              rangeText = {props.ranges[index]}
              domainText = {props.domains[index]}
              {...this.getParams()}
              count= {index + 1}
              handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
        />
    }
```